# How do I properly handle the incoming binary data from socket

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have binary image file that was sent package by package from the client(device). How can I properly handle this and save this to database so that to prevent in the future to have strip lines on the image after convertion.

```
var net  = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(socket){
    socket.on('end', function () {
        // somstuffhere();
    });
    socket.on('data',function(data){
         var revdata += data.toString('binary'); // receive first the buffer data.
     var checkdata = revdata.substr(-5);
     if(checkdata.substr(0,1) == '*'){
           var hexdata = new Buffer(revdata, 'ascii').toString('hex');
     // After converting to hex.Save database here..
       }else{
           revdata += data.toString('binary');
      }
});
server.listen(3020,'127.0.0.1', function () {
    console.log("server is up!");
});
```

The datatype of the column field is `VARCHAR(3072).` Does this make sense here?

Comment: You can't 'assum[e] receiving the complete 1 package data of binary image'. That's your first problem. TCP is a byte-stream, not a messaging protocol. As to whether 3072 is large enough for your images, only you can possibly know that.

Comment: 1. Nobody is going to follow links. 2. Material that forms part of a question must be included in the question. 3. As I have already stated, only you know how large your images are. But I would be using a `Blob` for this, not a `VARCHAR` with encoding.

Comment: If you use `Blob` and don't mess around with any encoding, the data will be saved as binary.

Comment: @EJP do I need still to use this var revdata += data.toString('binary'); in receiving or only like this var revdata += data.toString(); if I use blob.thank you in advance

Comment: I have no idea. I'll post the `Blob` suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `Blob` for this, not a `VARCHAR` with encoding. That way

- you don't have to decide in advance how big, and
- you don't have to do any encoding at all.